# Beginner to AX DYNAMICS Need clarification

Tags: installation, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

i would like to migrate to dymanics technical, i going to install dynamics in my laptop which has 500 gb hardsisk,4gb ram,win 7,icore 3 processor will it be okay for the software ? some saying it will got hangup and gives slow response am ready to upgrade hard disk and ram too , give me a better idea whether to buy a external hdd or to upgrade my laptop,Help me out got stuck

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11094) (a link to which could also be found on the AX 2012 download web pages: [CustomerSource](https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/product-releases/MSDYAX2012R3Release) and [PartnerSource](https://mbs.microsoft.com/partnersource/northamerica/deployment/downloads/product-releases/MSDYAX2012R3Release)),

- Server - 8 GB RAM is the minimum, 14 GB is recommended.
- Client - 2 GB RAM is the minimum, 4 GB is recommended.

If you have acces to PartnerSource you can [download](https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/service-packs/AX2012DemoToolsMaterials) an image of the virtual machine with AX 2012 demo and solution demos.

Comment: The virtual machine will be easier to setup, +1...  But the RAM recommendation goes up to 32 GB or more.